# How to fetch a content from directory using tool command language

Tags: tcl

I have a directory which contains some files and configurations ,now i have to fetch the content of this directory and have to run the script using TCL code .HOW can i write script for fetching the content from the directory.

Answer (score 2):

**glob** command returns names of files that match patterns

```
(Programs) 1 % glob *.bat
dl.bat get8.bat rfts.bat sdx.bat update.bat ws.bat zrm.bat
```

Answer (score 0):

Procedure which print content of requested directory

```
proc dir_content {dir_name} {
    puts [glob ${dir_name}/*]
}

dir_content [file normalize some_dir]
```

Comment: how it came to know where the directory is  located and how it will fetch the particular file from particular location.

Comment: @vinu some_dir variable supposed to contain relative or full path to the directory. In case it relative the command file normalize will return a unique normalized path representation for the file-system object (in this case full path to the directory) and the procedure dir_content will print some_dir content when each file prefaced by full path to his parent directory

Answer (score 0):

The `glob` command lists the contents of directories. It takes a pattern of files (or many patterns) to look for, and it also takes a number of options. We'll come back to those.

It's easiest to start with a simple example. Let's list the Tcl source files in the *current* directory:

```
glob *.tcl
```

The list comes back in a *random* order (it's not *really* random, but it depends on the OS and the filesystem and isn't easy to predict so it might as well be random). Let's get all the filenames and store them in a variable:

```
set allFiles [glob *]
# Really ought to use:
#    set allFiles [glob * .*]
# to also pick up all Unix hidden files.
```

But what about listing other directories? Well, by far the best option for that is the `-directory` option.

```
set theDir "~/Documents/examples"
set allFilesInDir [glob -directory $theDir *]
```

(You can put the directory in the pattern — `$theDir/*` — but trouble can arise for some directory names if you do that if you've got a clash between the file pattern metacharacters and the directory name. Better to be safe and use `-directory`.)

The other option that's really useful is `-nocomplain` so that when you list an empty directory you just get an empty list. (For historical reasons, without that option you'll end up with a — trappable — error when the results are empty otherwise.)

```
set allFilesInDir [glob -directory $theDir -nocomplain *]
```

There's more options (e.g., filtering by directory entry type with `-type`, filename trimming with `-tails`) but they're rather more complex and you normally don't need them. You've got enough to be dangerous enough for now…